# R - Find indices of first non zero elements in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I've got pannel data in the following form:

```
DT = data.table(Id=1:5, Time1=c(0,0,1,2,0), Time2=c(1,0,0,0,0), Time3=c(0,1,2,0,0), Time4=c(0,1,2,5,4))

Id  Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
1   0     1     0     0
2   0     0     1     1
3   1     0     2     2
4   2     0     0     5
5   0     0     0     4
```

I want to extrac the first time for every ID which is not 0. 
The dataset is large, therefore I was looking for a solution with data.table.

I tried something using which.min(which!=0), but could work it out.

The output should look as follows:

```
Id  Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4 Output
1   0     1     0     0     2
2   0     0     1     1     3
3   1     0     2     2     1
4   2     0     0     5     1
5   0     0     0     4     4
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
DT[, Output := which.max(.SD != 0), by = Id][]
#    Id Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4 Output
# 1:  1     0     1     0     0      2
# 2:  2     0     0     1     1      3
# 3:  3     1     0     2     2      1
# 4:  4     2     0     0     5      1
# 5:  5     0     0     0     4      4
```

`which.max` finds the index of the first occurrence of the maximum value.  So when we do `.SD != 0` it finds the first occurrence of `TRUE`.

Equivalently, we could also use

```
DT[, Output := match(TRUE, .SD != 0), by = Id]
# or 
DT[, Output := which(.SD != 0)[1], by = Id]
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do this in the case that DT is huge row-wise?